# AFNetworking, AFHTTPRequestOperationManager failing on operation when it's a 200 code

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking, slim, afhttprequestoperation

having an odd issue with AFNetworking recently. I have a PHP backend and I'm using the SLIM framework. Simplified example of what is happening: If I use the link http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/InstaAPI/hi this should be called:

```
$app->get('/hi', function() use($app) { 

    $app->response->setStatus(200);
    echo "hiiii\n";
});
```

Now in my objective-c code I have:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/InstaAPI/hi" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"ok");
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"fail");
        NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString);
    }];
```

The result I'm getting in the output console is:

```
015-10-08 18:30:20.650 iReporter[12822:3214201] fail
2015-10-08 18:30:20.650 iReporter[12822:3214201] hiiii
```

Have no idea why it's calling the failure block. The status is after all set to 200 so it should be okay. Could someone give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong here please?

Comment: Have you tried logging out the error from the fail block? It might shed some more light on this

Comment: ahh thanks man. Bit of a newb so didn't think checking like that. There was  a problem because the headers are set to JSON. If you see my echo "hiiii\n"; that isn't a JSON response. For some reason I thought I could debug using echoes scattered about. Obviously can't use them all if it's set to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Going to answer this myself. It turned out to be very simple. My headers are set to `'Content-Type', 'application/json'`. The line `echo "hiiii\n";` is not a JSON, so I had to use:

```
$response = array("Response"=>"HI!");
$echo json_encode($response);
```

The reason I was getting errors like this was because I was trying to debug the code by scattering echoes in stupid places to check where execution had got to in my PHP script. Moral of the story, don't use a single echo if your headers are set to JSON!